# Eager to know, synonym - What's he saying?

Tags: word-usage

What are Jeeves' exact words at 13.31 in this [episode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_CwiNVtuxE)?

Comment: At precisely 13:31 is silence. Do you mean "Agog" at 13:32, in "I am agog to learn, sir"?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's it. It's 13.31 here, must be a different time zone.

Comment: Videos from Youtube can be inaccessible in some countries or environments. Also, if the video gets take offline, the question will no longer be useful. Would it be possible for you to edit the word itself, and the context into your question text?

Comment: I don't see how this would be possible, given that the question specifically relates to an expression used in the video clip that I did not understand. Should I upload a sound file to a more accessible location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase you are asking about seems to be "I am agog to learn, sir."  Presumably, the word you are having trouble with is "[agog](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agog)":

> In eager desire, eager, astir.

In this case, it's used in a somewhat mocking manner; Jeeves doesn't truly care what Wooster has to say, he is just obligated, as a valet, to feign interest.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not having trouble with it, actually. In fact, I think it should be employed more often.

Comment: NB: Jeeves is a valet, not a butler—that is, he serves a man and not a household. However, "if the call comes, he can buttle with the best of them."